# Getting attribute of "cousins"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple inputs with the `.clickable` CSS class and a data attribute. The inputs are the only child of a `label` element. Some labels have the `.active` CSS class.
The basic structure looks like

```
<label class='[active]'>
  <input type='...' class='clickable' data-value='...'>
  text
</label>
```

Whenever I click a `'clickable` input I need to fetch the `data-value`s of all the inputs which are children of an `active` label.

Is there a simple way to achieve so with jQuery?

I'm trying using filtering and mapping but I'm basically stuck.

Comment: Is this you want? `$('label.active > input.clickable').each(function () { console.log($(this).data('value')) }`

Comment: "I need to fetch the `data-value`s" - how do you want them "fetched"?  In an array?  In a loop?

Comment: In an array. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input.clickable").click(function() {
    $("label.active > input.clickable").each(function() {
      console.log($(this).data("value"));
      // OR console.log($(this).attr("data-value"));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class='active'>
  <input type='text' placeholder="foo" class='clickable' data-value='hello_world_1'>
</label>

<label class='active'>
  <input type='text' placeholder="foo" class='clickable' data-value='hello_world_2'>
</label>
```

**References**
 1. https://api.jquery.com/data/
 2. https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/
 3. https://johnresig.com/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That may work. However, I may have other `label.active` with `input` which are not `clickable`.  Is there a way to remove those for the result set?